# Linux: How to connect to CRM 365 through Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics package?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

**CRM Dynamics 365 v9.1 on-premise**.

Linux, Mac OS

Microsoft provides official NuGet packages for Dynamics 365 v9.x [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/download-dynamics-365-sdk-v9?view=op-9-1). I have used this for several years. But they are for .Net Framework only (not for .Net Core/5/6).

Also exists official [Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics/) package. It is *preview* still but it can be used for .Net Core/5/6 also (according it's documentation).

I write some .Net 6 applications that communicate with CRM Dynamics 365 v.9. *They will be published into the docker images later*.

Right now I organized the communication via the [Dynamics Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/get-started-web-api?view=op-9-1): I create `HttpClient` with `NTLM` authentication. For connection I use login and password (they are stored in the system environment variables). It works fine on Mac OS:

```
static HttpClient CreateCrmHttpClient(string domain, string crmWebApiUrl, string authType, string crmLogin, 
    string crmPassword, Guid? callerId)
{
    var uri = new Uri(crmWebApiUrl);
    var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache
        {{uri, authType, new NetworkCredential(crmLogin, crmPassword, domain)}};

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = credentialsCache};

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) {BaseAddress = uri, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)};

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");

    if (callerId != null)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MSCRMCallerID", callerId.Value.ToString());
    }
    return httpClient;
}
```

Using example:

```
string domain = "MyCompany";
string crmWebApiUrl = "https://crm-dev.MyCompany.ru:456/MyCompany/api/data/v9.1/";
string crmLogin = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CrmLogin");
string crmPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CrmPassword");
Guid callerId = Guid.Parse("81CF7EFF-A996-44C2-8710-06E8177586C2"); // J.Smith
string authType = "NTLM";    

using (var httpClient = CreateCrmHttpClient(domain, crmWebApiUrl, authType, crmLogin, crmPassword, callerId)) {
  // ...
}
```

Also I want to learn to communicate with CRM throuh `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics` package using. But I have a problem with connecting to CRM. It doesn't provide capability to connect to CRM by `NTLM` authentication. I tried to connect with other different methods but unsuccessfully (I learned it's [examples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples)).

I need working code-example of connecting to CRM Dynamics 365 v9.1 on-premise through `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics` package using. I mean code example that works Linux or Mac.

Anybody has such experience? I would really appreciate a simple working code example!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding, from April 1, 2022, Microsoft has already made some changes to their authentication methods to the Microsoft Dataverse.  They no longer. Your `authType` wouldn't work anymore. See the second link for reference.  I personally have use ClientSecret and it connects fine with `Dynamics 365 SDK Version 9.1` or `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client` Nuget Package Version 1.0.1. You can try `AD` instead of `NTLM` as per second link for valid options for the `authType` parameter.

Reference: [Use of Office365 authentication with Microsoft Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-office365-deprecation)

Reference: [Use connection strings in XRM tooling to connect to Microsoft Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect)

Comment: I've read that references before I wrote my question. I not found the answer. Can you show your simple working example?

Comment: For example (about connection string using): `CrmServiceClient` class is defined in `Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly` what is for .Net Framework only. `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client` has not it.

Comment: You will need to swap your `CrmServiceClient` and use `ServiceClient` from the `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client`. If you are using early bound, you can directly pass `ServiceClient` to the `CrmDataContext` as a parameter to the constructor.